# Run a cats Resource in the infinite loop

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I want to run a program: Resource in the infinite loop. I tried `useForever`. The application does not close but the `program` (for content) runs only once.

```
val program: Resource[IO, Unit] = 
  for {
    _ <- Resource.eval(engine.createSth)
    _ <- Resource.eval(IO.sleep(2 seconds)
  } yield ()

program.useForever.as(ExitCode.Success)
```

Comment: Well `useForever` assumes that the created resource is running for ever, which is not what your code does. Without more context, I guess you don't need resource at all, just `foreverM` but maybe also `background`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.useForever` is used when you want to have a resource whose behavior is entirely in the acquire step. An example would be an http server. On resource acquire you bind to a port and start listening. Then it runs forever. All that `.useForever` does is prevent the resource from being closed. It's defined as `= use(_ => IO.never)`

Instead you want the `.foreverM` combinator, which repeatedly `flatMap`s some monadic program with itself in an endless loop.

```
program.foreverM
```

However in this case there's no resource behavior at *all* - it's just two independent actions that are being wrapped in resources. You can skip that and instead have

```
val run: IO[Nothing] = (engine.createSth >> IO.sleep(2.seconds)).foreverM
```